# Populating the TreeView controls' child nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm having trouble with populating the TreeView child nodes in my application. I don't know why my object: objProd does not want to load its entities from the line `objProd.ConsultationTypes.Load();` the load() function gives me this error:

> Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<_ConfigurationPortal.ConsultationType>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method
>   'Load' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<_360ClientConfigurationPortal.ConsultationType>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Programming\Source\Workspaces\360ClientConfigurationPortal\360ClientConfigurationPortal\MainPage.xaml.cs 151 51  360ClientConfigurationPortal

Here's my code block from where the object hails. This code block is the triggered event that responds when you click on a node to expand it.

```
private void ExpandLevel(TreeViewItem parentItem)
            {  
                if (parentItem.Header.Equals("Features"));                      // == typeof(Product)) //Check that the parent items are of type product as we want to fill their inner nodes.
                {
                    Product objProd = parentItem.Header as Product;             //Create instance object of type product
                    if (parentItem.Items.Count > 0)                             //Check if the product parent item has any children
                    {
                        object child = parentItem.Items.GetItemAt(0);           //First Child object set to * during first population
                        if (child.ToString() == "*")                            //If indeed it is a *
                        {                        
                            parentItem.Items.RemoveAt(0);                       //Remove the *

                            objProd.ConsultationTypes.Load();
                            //objProd.Name.ToList();

                            objProd.ConsultationTypes.OrderBy(l => l.Product).ToList().ForEach(l =>
                            {
                                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                                item.Header = l;
                                parentItem.Items.Add(item);

                                l.Consultations.OrderBy(a => a.ConsultationType).ToList().ForEach(a =>
                                {
                                    TreeViewItem attrItem = new TreeViewItem();
                                    attrItem.Header = a;
                                    item.Items.Add(attrItem);
                                });

                                if (l.Consultations.Count > 0)
                                    item.IsExpanded = true;
                            });

                            if (!parentItem.IsExpanded)
                                parentItem.IsExpanded = true;
                            parentItem.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I call the above code block by clicking on the root nodes created from the following code:

```
private void PopulateTreeview(SomeEntities ctx)
        {
            TreeViewItem rootItem = new TreeViewItem();
            RootItem root = new RootItem();
            root.Name = "Features";
            rootItem.Header = root.Name;
            productTreeView.Items.Add(rootItem);

            ctx.Products.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList().ForEach(d =>
            {
                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                item.Header = d.Name;
                item.Items.Add("*");
                rootItem.Items.Add(item);
            });

            rootItem.IsExpanded = true;
        }
```

The following is the function that actually keeps track of which node was clicked and then finally calls the actual ExpandLevel method that is meant to populate the child nodes with ConsultationTypes:

```
private void tvProducts_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
            ExpandLevel(item);
        }
```

And here is the relevant xaml:

```
    <TreeView 
                                            x:Name="productTreeView" 
                                            Margin="18,0,-18,0" 
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                            Height="300"
                                            TreeViewItem.Expanded="tvProducts_Expanded"
                                            >
                                        </TreeView>
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConsultationType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                <Image x:Name="Icon" Height="16" Width="16" Source="/Images/VSClass16.png" />
                <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ProductId}" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="." />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
private void GetTreeViewData()
        {
            List<Heirachi> result = new List<Heirachi>();
            //get all heirachi
            using (var c = new IWHSMacsteelEntities())
            {
               result  = (from p in c.Products
                             from ct in c.ConsultationTypes
                             where p.Id == ct.ProductId
                             orderby p.Id
                             select new Heirachi
                             {
                                 Name = p.Name,
                                 Code = ct.Code,
                                 ConsTypeDesc = ct.Name
                             }).ToList();



            }
            //distinct product
            var distinctResult = result.Select(s=>s.Name).Distinct();          

            //populate parent treeview
            TreeViewItem rootItem = new TreeViewItem();
            RootItem root = new RootItem();

            root.Name = "Features";
            rootItem.Header = root;
            productTreeView.Items.Add(rootItem);


            foreach (var dr in distinctResult)
            {
                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                item.Header = dr.ToString();
                //item.Items.Add("*");
                rootItem.Items.Add(item);

               //add children
                result.Where(s => s.Name == dr.ToString()).Select(s => s.ConsTypeDesc).ToList().ForEach(i =>
                    {
                        TreeViewItem childItem = new TreeViewItem();
                        childItem.Header = i.ToString();
                        //item.Items.Add("*");
                        item.Items.Add(childItem);

                    });

            }
            rootItem.IsExpanded = true;
        }
```

A big thanks to Bongolwethu for assisting me with coming up with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Explicit Loading:

```
var objectContext = (ctx as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
objectContext.LoadProperty(objProd, o => o.ConsultationTypes);
```

Instead of

```
objProd.ConsultationTypes.Load();
```

in method "ExpandLevel"

Comment: I'm getting an error due to LoadProperty from your answer:

Error 2 '_360ClientConfigurationPortal.IWHSMacsteelEntities' does not contain a definition for 'LoadProperty' and no extension method 'LoadProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationPortal.SomeEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Programming\Source\Workspaces\ConfigurationPortal\ConfigurationPortal\MainPage.xaml.cs 154 34 ConfigurationPortal

Comment: @Sizons try `var objectContext = (ctx as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;` and then `objectContext.LoadProperty(objProd, o => o.ConsultationTypes);`

Comment: I tried it this way as well and got some error on LoadProperty again.